# Displaying custom error messages in wp ninja forms

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

How can I show custom error messages in wordpress ninja forms plugin.
I have searched for ninja forms docs but unable to reach the site.
By default the error message is showing as 
 `This is a Required field.` 
I want it to be

```
Please enter respective field name.
```

Ninja forms form builder have the following options for validation.
[image: See the below image]
Is there a way to display this error message with respective field name?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this link, there are some hooks to get custom settings,

http://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/submission-processing-hooks/

on this link there is a filter,

**FILTER: ninja_forms_pre_validate_field_settings**

will be helpfull for you, you have to print_r($field_settings) and use your field conditions to get correct custom error message, sorry for my bad english, open to answer any question

Comment: will try it. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: this is really helpful. Thank u so much

Comment: @PrasannaVenkatesh. I am trying to put a custom message for my email error. Can you please help?

Comment: I tried to print the $field_settings but its not showing anything

Answer (score 2):

I have a rough jQuery solution that checks for any form changes/events and replaces the default error message for a specific input field.

```
$(document).on( 'nfFormReady', function( e, layoutView ) {

$('form').on('focus focusout keyup submit', 'input', function() {

    $('#nf-error-7 .nf-error-required-error').text('New Required Error Message');

});

});
```

I'm sure it can be adapted for multiple input types/fields.